# three.js json loader after r71

Tags: ruby-on-rails, three.js

I'm using three.js for a long time but stayed with r71 till now. I moved now to r76 and have a strange issue ; the json loader does not longer trigger the onLoadComplete function except if I it is a single existing function like beep() or alert("ok"). But of course this is not helpfull, I need at least to make scene.add(mesh) 
I checked with r72 and 74 and have the same issue. 
I tested by making a scene.add(mesh) with a Timer just to check if the object is well created by the loader.load function and this also works well. So I'm really stuck with the onLoadComplete not triggered. Did anyone have a clue on this ? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I never noticed or used onLoadComplete function, isn`t it just a relic from earlier implementation? searching in repo founds 
look at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/loaders/JSONLoader.js

AFAIK you should be able to load your files like this

```
var onLoadCallback = function(geometry, material){
    scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(geometry,material));
};
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "path/to/json.file", onLoadCallback);
```

Comment: Thank's for your feedback ; This is actually the way I initiate loading with a callback function including mapping texture image on material. But when there is a heavy texture file to map on the material, you cannot add the mesh to the scene before the texture file is fully loaded and mapped on the material. This requires also the callback function to do :  'material.onload=function() {material.map.needsUpdate = true;

Comment: if you look at the [TextureLoader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/loaders/TextureLoader.js) (used by JSONLoader by default) you can see it sets needsUpdate on the texture on its own at load `texture.needsUpdate = true;` so unless you have given it a Handler with custom loader it should update correctly(the mesh will be black for a while then a texture appears assuming render is called)

Comment: OK I was not aware on this and I will test this.  But I'm afraid the problem comes from something in my configuration because it works very well with r71. So I continue investigating what can be wrong in my config and will report when found. Thanks

Comment: OK, I tested this . You're right ; dont need the "onLoad Complete" and this brought out where my problem is really ; I use THREE.MorphAnimMesh and it says now : "is not a constructor". If I remove these it works. Thanks for putting me on a better track.

Comment: So, I just discovered the animation system has changed in r72 and I have to include manually older animation js ... and understand how I have to use the new stuff.